# How to connect a neutral wire from a bundle connected to a push in connector

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm planning on installing a smart dimmer switch but I'm not sure of the best way to connect the neutral wire. The outlet has 3 neutral wires bundled in a push in wire connector. What's the correct way to use  neutral wire in this case?

Should I pigtail a new wire into the existing push-in connector or replace it with a wire nut?

[image: Wiring Image]

Comment: Is there a fourth hole on the push-in connector?  Also, what make and model of smart dimmer are you planning to install?

Comment: Twist out the wires, throw the push connector in the trash, and get a wire nut.

Comment: I think there is a fourth hole but I’m not sure about push connectors in general. I’ve always used a wire nut. I’m planning on buying the Leviton smart dimmer.

Comment: @Harper -- since the connector has a hole spare, there's no need to throw it out (if it was full, I'd agree with replacing it with something that can handle more wires)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Push connectors usually have a narrow range of wire *size* and *strandedness* which they will permit. Smart switches often use 16AWG wire or even smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of connector has a fourth hole. I'd use it.

[image]

---

If it didn't, I'd twist out the wires and replace the connector with one of these lever operated connectors:

[image]

Comment: Provided that it's listed for the size of wire he is adding (and strandedness).

Comment: @Harper. Yes, good point. The one I show is rated pretty much the same as the yellow wire-nut and orange push-in connectors shown already in use in the OP's pic. [UL listed](http://www.wago.com/media/221/downloads_2/221_series_overview_ext.pdf) for up to 12 AWG solid, stranded or flexible.